# regex between <blocks with angle brackets> via egrep

Tags: regex, perl, grep

Given the following data how do i pull out the numbers between the physical-blocks angle brackets?

Raw data:

```
"6917: <physical-blocks> 573653840</physical-blocks>"
"8954: <physical-blocks>573653841</physical-blocks>"
"8991: <physical-blocks>573653842</physical-blocks>"
"9028: <physical-blocks>573653843</physical-blocks>"
"9065: <physical-blocks>573653844</physical-blocks>"
"9102: <physical-blocks>573653845</physical-blocks>"
```

desired output (array of):

```
573653840 573653841 573653842 573653843 573653844 573653845
```

I simply want to be able to extract data between `<physical-blocks>` and `</physical-blocks>`. Note; the full dataset include many strings with angle brackets - i specifically need the data between this specific set of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` version

```
awk '{sub(/[^>]*>/,"");sub(/<.*/,"");$1=$1}1' file
573653840
573653841
573653842
573653843
573653844
573653845
```

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk`:

```
gawk 'RT=="</physical-blocks>"' RS='</?physical-blocks>' ORS=' ' file
```

If you want newline after the output then see use the one below:

```
$ cat file
"6917: <physical-blocks>573653840</physical-blocks>"
"8954: <physical-blocks>573653841</physical-blocks>"
"8991: <physical-blocks>573653842</physical-blocks>"
"9028: <physical-blocks>573653843</physical-blocks>"
"9065: <physical-blocks>573653844</physical-blocks>"
"9102: <physical-blocks>573653845</physical-blocks>"

$ gawk 'RT=="</physical-blocks>";END{print "\n"}' RS='</?physical-blocks>' ORS=' ' file
573653840 573653841 573653842 573653843 573653844 573653845
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use simple lookahead and lookbehinds:

```
(?<=\>)(\s*)(\d*)(?=\<)
```

Comment: @user3376833 - When run against your dataset, it successfully captures the nine-digit numbers (held in `$2`).  What's the *"extraneous information"*?